# CSS style can't read with pug

Tags: vue.js, pug

Why does my `border-color` not work. I'm using pug and vue.js. It works until I add the "-" character, then it fails.

```
<template lang='pug'>
   div
      #section-one
          #grid
              .div(style={border-color: '0087de'})
```

Comment: corrected english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a javascript object to fill the styles. This is fine but `border-color` is not a valid key. You can use `'border-color'` (with quotes). Please also note the missing `#` in the color. This would result in:

```
<template lang='pug'>
   div
      #section-one
          #grid
              .div(style={'border-color': '#0087de'})
</template>
```

Comment: also you can write `style={borderColor: '#0087de'}` — camel-case is supported